# Stack for threads of a process in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, memory-management, process, operating-system

How is stack space allocated (in the same address space) to each thread of a process in Linux or any other OS for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of thread library, a user space library like pthreads would allocate memory and divide it into thread stacks. On the OS side each thread would get a kernel stack.

Answer (score 0):

On creation of new thread, the operating system reserves space in stack segment for current thread (parent), where the future auto variables and function call data of parent will live. Then, it allocates one guard page (this is to prevent the parent colliding into child stack, but this may vary with different operating systems). Once this is done, the stack frame for child thread is created (which is typically one-two page(s)).

This process is repeated in case the parent spawns multiple threads. All these stack frames live in stack segment of address space of process whose all these threads are part of.